# Java SealedObject

Tags: java, encryption

I am encrypting an string with PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC using SealedObject and write it to a file. After encrypting when i do a cat on the resulting file i i get read the salt used and the algorithm used in plain text even though the actual data is encrypted.

Doesn't that give crackers a head start? They know the salt and the algorithm with basically zero effort.

Answer (score 1):

The [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) isn't secret. Its purpose is generally to prevent dictionary attacks.

Keeping the algorithm secret is [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), which is pretty much universally discouraged.

Comment: security through obscurity is when you are using a weak algorithm and expect it to be safe if it not known this is not exactly the case here. also AFAIK when salt is known it will only prevent rainbow table attacks you can still try to guess it.

And during decryption i have to supply salt my self so it has no place in the SealedObject.

Answer (score 0):

When you use PBE (Password-Based Encryption), salt and iteration are just to make cracking more expensive. You only need to generate key once but guessers will have to try millions.

If you require salt to be secret, it defeats the purpose of the password. Password is something easy to remember but less secure. If you really worried about security, don't use password. Use a secret key.

Hiding salt is practically a double key scheme. In most cases, it doesn't make your cipher much stronger.